# RegEx for HTML tag conversion

Tags: php, html, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

For some reasons, I want to convert strings which contain

```
<p style=“text-align:center; others-style:value;”>Content</p>
```

to `<center>Content</center>` in PHP.

The text-align values can be either left, right, or center. And when there are other stylings, I want to omit them.

How can I do that in PHP?

**Edit:**

Maybe I was not clear enough in my original question. What I mean is that I want to convert contents with `text-align:center` to be wrapped by `<center>`, and contents with `text-align:right` to be wrapped by `<right>`. And when there is no text-align styling, I do not need any wrapping for that div. Thank you.

Comment: fyi, `<center></center>` is obsolete. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center "_This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it._"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might use a `preg_replace` to do so:

#### Test 1:

```
$test = preg_replace('/(<.*”>)(.*)(<\/.*)/s', '<center>$2</center>', '<p style=“text-align:center; others-style:value;”>Content</p>');

var_dump($test);
```

#### Output 1:

It would return:

```
string(24) "<center>Content</center>"
```

#### RegEx 1:

[The RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/Wb0DVR/1/) divides your inputs into three capturing groups, where the first and third groups can be assigned to open/close `p` tags.

[image]

#### RegEx 2:

You can further expand it, if you wish, with this [RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/9DjLq8/2) for any other tags/quotations/contents that you may want. It would divide any tags with any quotations (" or ” or ' or ’) into five groups where the fourth group (<kbd>$4</kbd>) is your target content. This type of RegEx may be usually useful for single occurrence non-looping strings, since it uses `(.*)`.

[image]

#### Test 2

```
$test = preg_replace('/<(.*)(\"|\”|\'|\’)>(.*)(<\/.*)/s', '<center>$4</center>', '<p style=“text-align:center; others-style:value;”>Content</p>');

var_dump($test);
```

#### RegEx 3

If you may wish to get any specific attributes in style, [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/9DjLq8/3) might help:

```
<(.*)(text-align:)(.*)(center|left|right|justify|inherit|none)(.*)(\"|\”|\'|\’)>(.*)(<\/.*)
```

[image]

#### Test 3

```
$tags = [
    '0' => '<p style=“text-align:center; others-style:value;”>Content</p>',
    '1' => '<div style=‘text-align:left; others-style:value;’ class=‘any class’>Any Content That You Wish</div>',
    '2' => '<span style=\'text-align:right; others-style:value;\' class=\'any class\'>Any Content That You Wish</span>',
    '3' => '<h1 style=“text-align:justify; others-style:value;” class="any class">Any Content That You Wish</h1>',
    '4' => '<h2 style=“text-align:inherit; others-style:value;” class=“any class">Any Content That You Wish</h2>',
    '5' => '<h3 style=“text-align:none; others-style:value;” class=“any class">Any Content That You Wish</h3>',
    '6' => '<h4 style=“others-style:value;” class=“any class">Any Content That You Wish</h4>',
];

var_dump($tag);

$RegEx = '/<(.*)(text-align:)(.*)(center|left|right|justify|inherit|none)(.*)(\"|\”|\'|\’)>(.*)(<\/.*)/s';
foreach ($tags as $key => $tag) {
    preg_match_all($RegEx, $tag, $matches);
    foreach ($matches as $key1 => $match) {
        if (sizeof($match[0]) > 0) {
            $tags[$key] = preg_replace($RegEx, '<$4>$7</$4>', $tag);
            break;
        }

    }

}

var_dump($tags);
```

#### Output 3

It would return:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(24) "<center>Content</center>"
  [1]=>
  string(38) "<left>Any Content That You Wish</left>"
  [2]=>
  string(40) "<right>Any Content That You Wish</right>"
  [3]=>
  string(44) "<justify>Any Content That You Wish</justify>"
  [4]=>
  string(44) "<inherit>Any Content That You Wish</inherit>"
  [5]=>
  string(38) "<none>Any Content That You Wish</none>"
  [6]=>
  string(86) "<h4 style=“others-style:value;” class=“any class">Any Content That You Wish</h4>"
}
```

Comment: But how do I get the text-align value?

Comment: Thanks!! What if I have two text-align elements in onw string, say the string is "<div style=‘text-align:left; others-style:value;’ class=‘any class’>Any Content That You Wish</div><p style=“text-align:center; others-style:value;”>Content</p>', any way to convert it to "<left>Any Content That You Wish</left><center>Content</center>" also? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Shouldn’t the end of tag be reference? Just so if someone puts a span in it it won’t break...