# How to perform regex tag conversions to all occurrences in a string in PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, replace, preg-replace

I want to convert my html strings which contain `<p style=“text-align:center; others-style:value;”>Content</p>` to `<center>Content</center>`, and `<p style=“text-align:right; others-style:value;”>Content</p>` to `<right>Content</right>` etc.

[My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55700611/) has an answer which can achieve this perfectly. Which is regex is:

```
$RegEx = '/<(.*)(text-align:)(.*)(center|left|right|justify|inherit|none)(.*)(\"|\”|\'|\’)>(.*)(<\/.*)/s';
$string = preg_replace($RegEx, '<$4>$7</$4>', $string);
```

However, my strings may contain more than one occurrences of the text-align. For example, I might have `<div style=‘text-align:left; others-style:value;’ class=‘any class’>Any Content That You Wish</div><p style=“text-align:center; others-style:value;”>Content</p>` I want it to become `<left>Any Content That You Wish</left><center>Content</center>`, but it would just output `<center>Content</center>`.

How can I get what I want in PHP? Many thanks.

Comment: Don't parse html using regex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi, I am converting html to non-html. What are the better ways?

Comment: It is recommended to use HTML parser for manipulating html text and transform to your desired structure. Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18349154/2102956.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi How can I get text-align values inside the style tag in html parser?

Comment: If there are no nested tags in your case, you can use this regex `<(?:(p|div)).*?\bstyle\s*=\s*[“"'‘]?text-align:([a-zA-Z]+).*?>(.*?)<\/\1>` and replace with `<$2>$3</$2>` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PewaCi/1)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi thank you, but how can I use it on PHP script? Seems when I try it, it says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '‘' (T_STRING) in ...". Probably it mistakenly think that some of the tags are closing tags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192026/discussion-between-pushpesh-kumar-rajwanshi-and-user2335065).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, you should not use regex for manipulating html content. But only if you have non-nested tags in your html, you can go for it.

For this particular case, you can use this regex,

```
<(p|div).*?\bstyle\s*=\s*.*?text-align:([a-zA-Z]+).*?>(.*?)</\1>
```

And replace it with `<\2>\3</\2>`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8ZQvnZ/1)**

[PHP code demo](https://rextester.com/BPZD56099)

```
$html = '<p style=“text-align:center; others-style:value;”>Content</p>
<div style=‘text-align:left; others-style:value;’ class=‘any class’>Any Content That You Wish</div><p style=“text-align:center; others-style:value;”>Content</p>';

$newhtml = preg_replace("~<(p|div).*?\bstyle\s*=\s*.*?text-align:([a-zA-Z]+).*?>(.*?)</\\1>~", '<\2>\3</\2>', $html);
echo $newhtml;
```

Prints,

```
<center>Content</center>
<left>Any Content That You Wish</left><center>Content</center>
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I encounter an issue: if my html content contains some paragraphs with no text-align at the very beginning, it will go missing after running the code. Example: `$html = '<p>First Paragraph</p><p style=“text-align:center; others-style:value;”>Content</p>
<div style=‘text-align:left; others-style:value;’ class=‘any class’>Any Content That You Wish</div><p style=“text-align:center; others-style:value;”>Content</p>';`

The `<p>First Paragraph</p>` would disappear while I still want it to be retained. Thank you!